# Failing to create a new record in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm attempting to create a new `StockOrder` by passing a JSON object from my front end to the server. The defined strong parameters for the `StockOrders` looks like this:

```
private
  def stock_order_params
    params.require(:stock_order).permit( [StockOrder.strong_params, :purchaser_id, :carriage_terms, :carriage_cost, :contact_id, :user_id, :currency, :default_vat_rate, :discount_cost, :dispatched_status, :due_date, :internal_notes, :invoice_address_id, :invoice_date, :payment_terms, :po_date, :vat_rate, :purchase_order_number, {stock_order_line_items_attributes: [StockOrderLineItem.strong_params, :_destroy, :id, :part_id, :description, :quantity, :unit_cost, :vat_rate, :quantity_to_dispatch, :sort_index] + StockOrderLineItem.additional_params}, :purchaser_notes, :delivery_address] + StockOrder.additional_params )
  end
```

In this you can see that I have two models: `StockOrder` & `StockOrderLineItem`.

Here is what I'm sending from my front-end:

```
{
 "stock_order":
    {
     "stock_order_line_items_attributes":
        {
         "part_id":2309,"unit_cost":15,
         "quantity_to_dispatch":5
        },
     "contact_id":10,
     "purchaser_id":10
    }
 }
```

And finally here is how I'm trying to create my new `StockOrder`:

```
@stock_order = StockOrder.new(stock_order_params)
```

But the server responds with this error:

[image: Rails controller error]

But I've looked at the models for both and, of the parameters that I'm passing, none of them are strings. Here's a snapshot of the schema for the tables:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: stock_orders
#
#  id                        :integer          not null, primary key
#  ref_no                    :integer
#  purchase_order_number     :string
#  contact_id                :integer
#  purchase_order_date       :date
#  carriage_terms            :text
#  payment_terms             :text
#  due_date                  :date
#  purchaser_id              :integer
```

And for the `StockOrderItemList`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: stock_order_line_items
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  stock_order_id         :integer
#  part_id                :integer
#  quantity               :decimal(, )
#  vat_rate               :float
#  unit_cost_cents        :integer
#  net_cost_cents         :integer
#  total_cost_cents       :integer
#  vat_cost_cents         :integer
#  local_unit_cost_cents  :integer
#  local_net_cost_cents   :integer
#  local_total_cost_cents :integer
#  local_vat_cost_cents   :integer
#  quantity_dispatched    :decimal(, )
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#  description            :text
#
```

**EDIT**

This is what the `puts.stock_order_params.class` prints out

```
Parameters: {
  "stock_order"=>{
    "stock_order_line_items_attributes"=>{
      "part_id"=>2309, 
      "unit_cost"=>15, 
      "quantity_to_dispatch"=>5
    }, 
    "contact_id"=>10, 
    "purchaser_id"=>10}
 }
```

**EDIT 2**

```
19:34:59 web.1    | App 31944 stdout: ----------------------HERE!-------------------------
19:34:59 web.1    | App 31944 stdout:   MagicField Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "magic_fields".* FROM "magic_fields" WHERE "magic_fields"."model_owner" = $1  [["model_owner", "StockOrder"]]
19:34:59 web.1    | App 31944 stdout:   MagicField Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "magic_fields".* FROM "magic_fields" WHERE "magic_fields"."model_owner" = $1  [["model_owner", "StockOrderLineItem"]]
19:34:59 web.1    | App 31944 stdout: ActionController::Parameters
19:34:59 web.1    | App 31944 stdout: ----------------------THERE!-------------------------
```

Comment: try to do `puts stock_order_params.class` or `puts stock_order_params.inspect` before @stock_order = `StockOrder.new(stock_order_params)` and this will give you clear idea on what you're dealing with.

Comment: @imechemi done - see my edit

Comment: That's not possible if you're trying to print `stock_order_params.class`. It should print type of the data which could be either JSON, Hash or String. It should not print the content of the strong params.

Comment: @imechemi let me try again. I wrapped them up with "------HERE-------" so I can make sure it's correct. See my edit again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the relation between `StockOrder` and `StockOrderItems` is a One-to-many relationship.

See [this guide to nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-One-to-many).

You should send to your controller an array of `stock_order_line_items` hashes instead of a single one hash (which is for [One-to-One relationships](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-One-to-one)).

That is to say:

```
{
 "stock_order": {
     "stock_order_line_items_attributes": [
        {
         "part_id":2309,
         "unit_cost":15,
         "quantity_to_dispatch":5
        }
     ],
     "contact_id":10,
     "purchaser_id":10
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is an `has_many` association, your parameters should be like:

```
Parameters: {
  "stock_order"=>{
    "stock_order_line_items_attributes"=>[
      {
        "part_id"=>2309, 
        "unit_cost"=>15, 
        "quantity_to_dispatch"=>5
      }
    ], 
    "contact_id"=>10, 
    "purchaser_id"=>10
  }
}
```